# Communication code between nrf24l01's suddenly not working. Hardware is fine

Tags: nrf24l01+, wireless

I specifically had saved code for the purpose of checking the connection, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

All the examples from this [simple tutorial](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123/4) work, so it can't be a hardware issue.

Maybe someone can find a reason why the code wouldn't work? It returns radio.available() as false

```
//Transmitter
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002"};
float valueTransmit;
float valueRecieved;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]); // 00002
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]); // 00001
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  valueTransmit = 0
}
void loop() {
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.write(&valueTransmit, sizeof(valueTransmit));
  delay(5);

  radio.startListening();
  if (radio.available() ) {
      radio.read( &valueRecieved, sizeof(valueRecieved) );
  Serial.print(valueRecieved);
  valueTransmit = valueRecieved + 0.01;
  }
}




//Reciever
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002"};
float valueTransmit;
float valueRecieved;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]); // 00001
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[1]); // 00002
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
}
void loop() {
  radio.startListening();
  if (radio.available() ) {
    radio.read( &valueRecieved, sizeof(valueRecieved) );
    Serial.print(valueRecieved);
    valueTransmit = valueRecieved + 1;
  }
  
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.write(&valueTransmit, sizeof(valueTransmit));
  delay(5);

}
```

Comment: `suddenly not working` means that it was working and it failed without any changes ... is that what happened?

Comment: @jsotola Honestly it's been a while since I wrote that code, so can't be too sure. But I remember being happy to finally see it working and pasting it into a notepad. If I did any changes, it was just to make it flow/look better.

Comment: Also, I had tried to edit the tutorial example code to work with just integers and adding up numbers and made [this](https://pastebin.com/5wqmsPpH) to show what I changed. That also made it stop working and I couldn't figure out why. It's not like I changed anything critical, just the data that it sends.